# Mac Mail install default signature

Tags: python, macos, email, plist

I'm trying to create a python script which installs a default signature for a Mac Mail account. So far, my script successfully installs the signature by manipulating `ubiquitous_AllSignatures.plist` and creating a corresponding `ubiquitous_<SignatureId>.mailsignature`. Both of these files are at `~/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~mail/Data/V3/MailData/Signatures/`. The problem is the installed signature is not recognized by Mail as the default signature, and in order to use the signature you have to manually select it in the signature dropdown while composing an email.

I've searched the file system long and hard to find a relevant plist which dictates the 'default' signature behavior for a given account. I have grep'd for the Signature ID and the only place I can see it other than the places mentioned above is in the sqlite files in `~/Library/Application Support/CloudDocs/session/db/`. I don't think this is a good sign for the feasibility of my default signature install.

I understand this is a very specialized/weird/hacky problem, but I'm looking for some insight into the underlying mechanism controlling the default signature for an account in Mac Mail, or at least confirmation of my suspicions that it's impossible to do this without the consent of Mail. Any feedback is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I realize this is incredibly obscure, but because I have been helped greatly by self-answers to obscure questions I'm gonna try to help anyone who may face this problem in the future.

The 'default' signature is indeed set in a plist. This plist is `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.mail/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.mail.plist`. Be weary, this is a binary plist, which is different and much less readable than an xml plist. But fear not, you can transform back and forth b/w binary and xml with the `plutil` utility. You can access this utility in python with [biplist](https://github.com/wooster/biplist), hooray! Now it's just a matter of manipulating the `SignaturesSelected` dictionary within the plist by adding the signature id (string) for the account id (key). And you will have set your default signature!